# Create Bootable Ubuntu O/S Backups

Tags: server, backup

I have been searching for a backup tool that would allow me to create a bootable copy of the Ubuntu 18.04 Server (or higher) operating system image that is installed on any of my machines.

I come from an IBM AIX background. On that platform, there are a couple of tools that can be used (mksysb, mkdvd) that allow you to generate an image of the O/S and the way it is currently configured. In the event of a DR situation, you are able to slip the DVD into the drive, boot the system, and it will go ahead and re-install exactly as it was at the time the backup was made. These are HOT backups. You do not need to have the users logged off.

In Ubuntu, what I found so far was that there is no easy solution to generate an ISO of how the system is installed at this moment. Most open-source packages I found require that the server be rebooted into some sort of maintenance mode to be able to create the media needed. On a production server, that means getting all other users off and/or shutting down over a weekend, provided the system is not used 24/7.

Does anyone have a routine or a product they use to back up just the Ubuntu operating system, in a manner that can be restored back to the way it was? I mean not having to recreate users and passwords, keep any printers that have been defined, save the netplan, hosts, services files, etc.

Our servers are all installed with the O/S on one RAID-1 set of disks (rootvg), and any databases installed in a separate RAID-5 array on a separate volume group (datavg), if that helps. The idea being that we can re-install or upgrade the Ubuntu on rootvg without affecting the data in the other volume group (s).

Comment: Hello. You have to keep in mind even if you find such a software you will have issues. When you take the drive to another machine who says all the hardware will be exactly the same? The graphics card could leave you with a blank black screen as there is no driver for it in your install. Also what about the UEFI setting and the GRUB? It could be as simple as a motherboard differnt chip set will cause the installed system to fail. Good Luck.

Comment: Some discussion here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436006 & https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rsync#Full_system_backup But you are correct to get everything system has to be down. Often suggestions are not to backup Ubuntu as that can be easily reinstalled, but backup /home. etc, list of installed apps and any server app folders in /. Data bases may have their own better way to backup data.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your perspectives. The main concern is if we have proprietary software that is expecting Ubuntu 18.04 with specific packages or libraries, we may need to rebuild using the same apt packages that were there before the disaster situation. Being able to restore all the same packages, then have Ubuntu install any new ones it may need for changed hardware, was the thought process. But I do see your points. We are saving /etc files (hosts, cups, netplan) and our CRON jobs from /var/spool/cron, but was hoping there would be a better way.